# Transposing and multiplying lists in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, duplicates, transpose

I have 2 dimensional list/matrix which is dynamic with `N` rows and `M` columns.

[image: Sample Matrix]

The data type within a particular column is uniform, example: col1 is text, col2 is integer, column3 is float etc.
The order of the columns can be different. Values for certain rows can be also missing.

Expected result should be 2 lists/arrays/dataframes, where:

- `list1` should be duplicated `N` times (depending the number of rows) `col1_r1, col1_r2, ....., colM_row_n`, with appended iterator or the number of rows
- `list2` should be transposed values of the rows (including the empty ones)

What is the best way to achieve this in Python 3.6 using native lists or/and numpy arrays or/and panda dataframes?

```
output_list1 = [col1_1, col1_2, col1_3, col1_4, col1_5, col2_1, col2_2, 
                col2_3, col2_4, col2_5, col3_1, col3_2, col3_3, col3_4, col3_5]
```

-

```
output_list2 = ["value-row1,col1", "", "value-row3,col1",   "value-row4,col1",  
                ",value-row5,col1", "value-row1,col2", "value-row2,col2",   "value-row3,col3",  
                0,  "value-row5, col5", "value-row1, col3", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "value-row5,col4"]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How matrix is stored? Is it some list of lists or something else?

Comment: It is a list of lists.

Comment: List of columns or list of rows?

Comment: It's a list of lists of columns. I'm parsing one html file which has lots of tables inside. I was able to create a numpy array of a particular list, so at row0, colM I have the list header that needs to be duplicated, while at row1+dim(array) I have the remaining data which needs to be transposed.
# Getting the 6th list from my "file" list
a = np.array(file[0][6])
# Get the shape
print(a.shape)
# (11, 6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np

# create the data in a nested list
data_list = [['Event', 'Waits', 'Total Wait Time (sec)', 'Wait Avg(ms)', '% DB time', 'Wait Class'], 
             ['latch free', '15,625', '311', '19.91', '29.6', 'Other'], 
             ['library cache: mutex X', '90,012', '117,8', '1.31', '11.2', 'Concurrency'], 
             ['DB CPU', '\xa0', '87,3', '\xa0', '8.3', '\xa0']]

# transform into numpy object array
data_array = np.array(data_list, dtype=object)
# construct header from first row
header = data_array[0, :]
# only use the data part of the array
data = data_array[1:, :]

list1 = []
list2 = []
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data.shape[1]):
        # adjust for the 1 based index of row numbers
        # transpose header columns by switching indices i and j
        list1.append('{}_{}'.format(header[j], i+1))
        # populate flattened data list
        list2.append(data[i,j])

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
list1 = ['Event_1', 'Waits_1', 'Total Wait Time (sec)_1', 'Wait Avg(ms)_1', '% DB time_1', 'Wait Class_1', 'Event_2', 'Waits_2', 'Total Wait Time (sec)_2', 'Wait Avg(ms)_2', '% DB time_2', 'Wait Class_2', 'Event_3', 'Waits_3', 'Total Wait Time (sec)_3', 'Wait Avg(ms)_3', '% DB time_3', 'Wait Class_3']
list2 = ['latch free', '15,625', '311', '19.91', '29.6', 'Other', 'library cache: mutex X', '90,012', '117,8', '1.31', '11.2', 'Concurrency', 'DB CPU', '\xa0', '87,3', '\xa0', '8.3', '\xa0']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help WofgangK. This is very close, to what I am looking for. Perhaps I didn't desccribe it well.

data_array = [['Event', 'Waits', 'Total Wait Time (sec)', 'Wait Avg(ms)', '% DB time', 'Wait Class'], ['latch free', '15,625', '311', '19.91', '29.6', 'Other'], ['library cache: mutex X', '90,012', '117,8', '1.31', '11.2', 'Concurrency'], ['DB CPU', '\xa0', '87,3', '\xa0', '8.3', '\xa0']]

data_array[0] is the header of the list that needs to be duplicated N times, in this case 3 times. The hdr name needs to be the same as values the list, just with appended value of the iterat

Comment: Just to clarify: what you want is for list1 to look like `list1 = ['Event_1', 'Event_2', 'Event_3', 'Waits_1', ..., 'Wait Class_3']`? Is list2 similar to what you're looking for?

Comment: The transpose should be done not on the whole data set at once, but on a column-per-column basis. Example:

list1 = 'Event_1', 'Waits_1', 'Total Wait Time (sec)_1', 'Wait Avg(ms)_1', '% DB time_1', 'Wait Class_1', 'Event_2', 'Waits_2', 'Total Wait Time (sec)_2', 'Wait Avg(ms)_2', '% DB time_2', 'Wait Class_2' etc. 

list2 = 'latch free', '15,625', '311', '19.91', '29.6', 'Other', 'library cache: mutex X', '90,012', '117,8', '1.31', '11.2', 'Concurrency'

Comment: Updated for new information. Double `for` loops used for clarity. If you have lots of data, numpy should be used to get rid of those to improve speed.